# How to sort NSMutableArray using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a question about sorting `NSMutableArray`. I can use `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method to sort an array with objects.

For example  I have  an `NSMutableArray` of `places` where I have an attribute `frequency` (int value) and I want to sort descending on `frequency` but I don't know how to use it correctly.

**What do I put as a key in `initWithKey`?**

My object `place` contains:

```
NSString * name;
NSString * address;
NSString * frequency;
NSString * type;
```

---

```
NSMutableArray * places;

... populate array with objects ...

NSSortDescriptor * sortByFrequency =
   [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"????????" ascending:NO] autorelease];

NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByFrequency];
NSArray * sorted = [x sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Comment: Argh! This is tough to understand. Please, babyDeveloper, use punctuation (mostly periods and commas) in your questions.

Comment: You say this "frecuency" is an int value, but your code says it's an NSString. Please take care to phrase your questions clearly.

Answer (score 111):

To sort your array of objects you:

1. setup `NSSortDescriptor` - use names of your variables as keys to setup descriptor for sorting plus the selector to be executed on those keys
2. get the array of descriptors using `NSSortDescriptor` that you've setup
3. sort your array based on those descriptors

Here are two examples, one using `NSDictionary` and `NSString/NSNumber` values sorting on `NSNumber`, the other one using custom class with sorting on two `NSString` fields.

Follow [Sorting and Filtering NSArray Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/index.html) in Cocoa programming topics to see more examples and explanation.

**Example**:

*This was done on GNUStep it should work the same on Cocoa - the code is exactly the same - I'll try when I sit in front of my Mac:*

**First example using `NSString` and `NSNumber` values with sorting on `NSNumber` value:**

```
NSString * NAME      = @"name";
NSString * ADDRESS   = @"address";
NSString * FREQUENCY = @"frequency";
NSString * TYPE      = @"type";

NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];

NSDictionary * dict;

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            @"Alehandro", NAME, @"Sydney", ADDRESS,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], FREQUENCY,
            @"T", TYPE, nil];
[array addObject:dict];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            @"Xentro", NAME, @"Melbourne", ADDRESS,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:50], FREQUENCY,
            @"X", TYPE, nil];
[array addObject:dict];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            @"John", NAME, @"Perth", ADDRESS,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:75],
            FREQUENCY, @"A", TYPE, nil];
[array addObject:dict];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            @"Fjord", NAME, @"Brisbane", ADDRESS,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], FREQUENCY,
            @"B", TYPE, nil];
[array addObject:dict];
```

---

Sorting part using descriptors with the Frequency field which is `NSNumber`:

```
NSSortDescriptor * frequencyDescriptor =
    [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:FREQUENCY
                                 ascending:YES] autorelease];

id obj;
NSEnumerator * enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject])) NSLog(@"%@", obj);

NSArray * descriptors =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frequencyDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray =
    [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

NSLog(@"\nSorted ...");

enumerator = [sortedArray objectEnumerator];
while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject])) NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

---

**OUTPUT - sorted by Frequency field:**

```
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Sydney; frequency = 100; name = Alehandro; type = T; }
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Melbourne; frequency = 50; name = Xentro; type = X; }
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Perth; frequency = 75; name = John; type = A; }
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Brisbane; frequency = 20; name = Fjord; type = B; }
2009-12-04 x[1]
Sorted ...
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Brisbane; frequency = 20; name = Fjord; type = B; }
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Melbourne; frequency = 50; name = Xentro; type = X; }
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Perth; frequency = 75; name = John; type = A; }
2009-12-04 x[1] {address = Sydney; frequency = 100; name = Alehandro; type = T; }
```

---

---

**Second example with custom class and sorting on two `NSString` variables.**

Array to sort (see class `A` at the bottom):

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:[[A alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Alehandro"
                                     lastName:@"Xentro"
                                          age:[NSNumber numberWithInt:40]]];
[array addObject:[[A alloc] initWithFirstName:@"John"
                                     lastName:@"Smith"
                                          age:[NSNumber numberWithInt:30]]];
[array addObject:[[A alloc] initWithFirstName:@"John"
                                     lastName:@"Smyth"
                                          age:[NSNumber numberWithInt:25]]];
[array addObject:[[A alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Torro"
                                     lastName:@"Ola"
                                          age:[NSNumber numberWithInt:45]]];
[array addObject:[[A alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Alehandro"
                                     lastName:@"Bento"
                                          age:[NSNumber numberWithInt:41]]];
[array addObject:[[A alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Alehandro"
                                     lastName:@"Axel"
                                          age:[NSNumber numberWithInt:41]]];
```

---

The sorting part, sort on lastName then firstName:

```
NSString * LASTNAME = @"lastName";
NSString * FIRSTNAME = @"firstName";

NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
    [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:LASTNAME
          ascending:YES
           selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

NSSortDescriptor *firstDescriptor =
    [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:FIRSTNAME
          ascending:YES
           selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

NSArray * descriptors =
   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lastDescriptor, firstDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray =
   [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

---

Print the result:

```
NSLog(@"\nSorted ...");

enumerator = [sortedArray objectEnumerator];
while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject])) NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

---

Result (before and after sorting):

```
2009-12-04 00:52:16.637 x[11375] Alehandro, Xentro, age:40
2009-12-04 00:52:16.644 x[11375] John, Smith, age:30
2009-12-04 00:52:16.644 x[11375] John, Smyth, age:25
2009-12-04 00:52:16.644 x[11375] Torro, Ola, age:45
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] Alehandro, Bento, age:41
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] Alehandro, Axel, age:41
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375]
Sorted ...
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] Alehandro, Axel, age:41
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] Alehandro, Bento, age:41
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] Torro, Ola, age:45
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] John, Smith, age:30
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] John, Smyth, age:25
2009-12-04 00:52:16.645 x[11375] Alehandro, Xentro, age:40
```

Class `A` extends `NSObject` - nothing special here:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject
{
    NSString * firstName;
    NSString * lastName;
    NSNumber * age;
}

- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString*)aFirstName
               lastName:(NSString*)aLastName
                    age:(NSNumber*)anAge;

-(NSString* )description;
+(NSString*)action;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "A.h"

@implementation A

- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithFirstName:@"N/A"
                          lastName:@"N/A"
                               age:0];
}

- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString*)aFirstName
               lastName:(NSString*)aLastName
                    age:(NSNumber*)anAge
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    firstName = [aFirstName copy];
    lastName = [aLastName copy];
    age = [anAge copy];

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [firstName release];
    [lastName release];
    [age release];
    [super release];
}
```

---

```
- (NSString *) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@, %@, age:%@",
                                       firstName, lastName, age];
}
@end
```

Comment: awesome answer, and helped me understand how to sort an NSMutableArray :) and i'm just starting with all this so good work!!!

Answer (score 2):

The "key" is a method of your objects (the elements of your array "x") that returns the thing you want to sort by. So in this case, you said that you want to sort by the "frequency". Then all you have to do is use the name of the method that returns the frequency, as the key.

Comment: Although it would have to be of a numeric type, such as `int` (preferably `unsigned`), `NSUInteger`, `double`, or `NSNumber *`. With the frequency values as strings, they won't sort numerically (not without a custom comparator, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how a would sort an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *numberSort =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        //(NSNumber *)integer = [key integerValue];
        [numberSort  addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[key intValue]]];
        // code that uses the returned key 
    }


    NSArray *stringSort = [numberSort sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    enumerator = [stringSort objectEnumerator];
    NSNumber  *intKey;

    NSMutableArray *backToString =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while ((intKey = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        //(NSNumber *)integer = [key integerValue];
        [backToString  addObject:[intKey stringValue]];
        // code that uses the returned key
```