# how to sort NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Having trouble with something basic (I think).

I have an NSMutable array that I populate with "workout" objects.  The "startDate" method returns an NSDate - and I'd like to sort the array off this.

The NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate line terminates due to an uncaught exception.  What's wrong here?

```
NSMutableArray *workouts;
workouts = [[[Workout findByCriteria:@"where state = %@ order by pk desc", 
  [NSNumber numberWithInt:WorkoutStateComplete]] mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor 
  sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
[workouts sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByDate]];
```

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: Kenny - I looked at many links, but didn't see this one.  Close enough to set me straight.  Thank you.

Comment: Jeremy - never told me more info about the exception

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors/1845165#1845165

Answer (score 0):

Make sure none of the objects in the workouts array have `startDate` set to nil or return nil. Also make sure that all objects in the array respond to the `startDate` selector.