# Sorting an Array with Strings that contains Numbers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting NSString values as if NSInteger using NSSortDescriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674707/sorting-nsstring-values-as-if-nsinteger-using-nssortdescriptor)

I have an Array that I fill with my NSMutableDictionary.. and I use this:

```
myArray =[[myDict allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(IDONTKNOW:)];
```

AllKeys of myDicts are NSStrings... like 123.423 or 423.343... I need to sort the new myArray by incremental numbers.. 12.234    45.3343    522.533   5432.66 etc etc

What must insert in @selector to do this properly? Thanks

Comment: have a look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38347576/5165668

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use an [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and pass `doubleValue` as the key.

```
//sfloats would be your [myDict allKeys]
NSArray *sfloats = @[ @"192.5235", @"235.4362", @"3.235", @"500.235", @"219.72" ];
NSArray *myArray = [sfloats sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                    @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"doubleValue" 
                                                    ascending:YES]]];

NSLog(@"Sorted: %@", myArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't direclty use `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`.   Use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` and implement a comparison block yourself.

Kinda like this q/a:

[Changing the sort order of -[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054921/changing-the-sort-order-of-nsarray-sortedarrayusingcomparator)

(In fact, that Question's code can likely be copy/pasted into your code and it'll "just work" once you change it from `integerValue` to `doubleValue` for the four convert-string-to-number calls):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    double n1 = [obj1 doubleValue];
    double n2 = [obj2 doubleValue];
    if (n1 > n2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (n1 < n2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: Great answer! Save my day

Answer (score 0):

Consider `sortedArrayUsingFunction:`.  This allows you to define a custom comparison function to employ when comparing elements.

```
myArray =[[myDict allKeys]sortedArrayUsingFunction:SortAsNumbers context:self];   

NSInteger SortAsNumbers(id id1, id id2, void *context)
{
    float v1 = [id1 floatValue];
    float v2 = [id2 floatValue];
    if (v1 < v2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (v1 > v2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

More info available here: [Sort NSArray using sortedArrayUsingFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147218/sort-nsarray-using-sortedarrayusingfunction#5147284)