# how to modify this method call so it sorts using sortdescriptors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to have the following method call, sorted. Can I use sortdescriptors? If so how should I do it?

```
NSArray *subcategoriesNames = [self.dataManager getSubcategoriesOfCategory:self.category];
for (SubcategoryEntity *subcategory in subcategoriesNames) {
      NSLog(@"print all subcategories %@",subcategory.icon);
      NSLog(@"print all subcategories %@",subcategory.title);
      BaseTableItem *item = [[BaseTableItem alloc] initWithText:subcategory.title andIcon:subcategory.icon];
        [self.tableItems addObject:item];
        [item release];
```

I need that subcategoriesNames gets sorted before its used in the loop.

`Datamanager` is a `Coredata` object. Its retrieving a set of rows from a database, each row has a title and an icon. I need the sort to happen by title.

Comment: David how do you get the code to show like that?

Comment: You indent it by 4 spaces, or (easier) click on the button with the "{}" icon

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort NSMutableArray using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors) -- very good answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible duplicate of How to sort NSMutableArray using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors ? -- very good answers there. – David Gelhar Apr 18 at 2:41