# sorting an array of NSObject based on one value based on one value within one object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsobject

i have created an object, it looks something like this

```
aOffice.branchname 
aOffice.lat
aOffice.lng
aOffice.distance
```

this is then added to an mutable array (nearbranch).
later on i work out the distance of each object to the current gps position and add that into the object and put it back into the array. (aOffice.distance)

i now need to sort that array based on the value of aOffice.distance but have no idea how to do it

could someone help me out please

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256046/how-to-sort-nsarray-of-objects-based-on-one-attribute use this link

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:NO]];
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: this is perfect, it works. i have no idea how it does, but ill look into it now