# Objective C custom array sorting algorithm error

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsmutablearray, comparator

I am sorting an array of custom winery objects by a name attribute.

```
wineryNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[wineryNames sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Winery *a, Winery *b){
    return [a.getName compare:b.getName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}]];
```

I am receiving an error on the return line and the log says 'unrecognized selector'.  I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Is `wineryNames` definitely an array containing `Winery` objects? And, what does the `@interface` declaration for the Winery class look like? Does it have a method or property called `getName`?

Comment: Thank you so much esker. It was an array containing NSString objects, not Winery objects.  I don't know why I didn't see it, I guess it was just make my head hurt type code and I made a few other classes with code similar to what I posted.  But thank you - it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the job:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                  selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedArray = [wineryNames sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

More info [Here!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256848/2611971)