# sorting UITableview cells by creation order swift

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8, xcode6, tableview

Right now I have a tableview that loads data from coredata and I would like to know how it is possible to order these cells by their order of creation. I'd like for the user to be able to see the most recent cells created at the top of the tableview.

Thanks.

Comment: Sort the array of results based on a date property. [Here's how.][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6256848/1228075

Comment: Don't think of it as "the most recent cells created" but rather the most recent data object created

Comment: Ok, so how would I sort by the most recent data object created?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Add a sort descriptor to your request:

   ```
   //Entity
   NSString *entityName = @"Days";

   //Fetch Request
   NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

   //Sort
   request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:YES]];
   ```
2. Sort the array of results:

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"DatePropertyName" ascending:YES];
   NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]; 
   NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
   ```