# Help sorting an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have to sort this array in descening order with the key "likecount". **How can I sort it by specific key?** This text is my output which coming on console:

```
source id key is (
    {

    2 = likecount;
    "This wall post is not from application. Direct from website." = message;
},

    {
    0 = likecount;
    "New integration" = message;
},
    {
    1 = likecount;
    "This is beta testing.. yes" = message;
},

    {
    2 = likecount;
    "hello wall testing.." = message;
}
```

)

I tried this below code but not getting any result. Still output is without sorted.

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"likecount" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortdescriptor=[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
NSArray *sortedarray=[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortdescriptor];


  NSLog(@"source sorting id key is %@",sortedarray);
 NSLog(@"source s@@@@@@  id key is %@",array);
```

// array is variable which is holding actual content

Comment: I tried by this link but not getting output. I might be my error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [`NSSortDescriptor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html) should work for you. Try something like this

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortd = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"likecount"
                                           ascending:NO] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortd];
sortedArray = [sourceArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: I implemented above code but nothing happening on data. Here is my code.  NSSortDescriptor *sortd = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"likecount"
                                                           ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortd];
    
       NSLog(@"source sorting id key is %@",sortDescriptors);
    
    NSArray * sortedArray  = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 
printing sortDescriptors  key is (
    "(likecount, ascending, compare:)"
) and remaining output is same.

Comment: What does your collection consist of? custom classes? dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using below code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"likecount" ascending:YES];
[self.msgHistory sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];   

[descriptor release];
```