# How to sort a Array based on it's object's property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, properties, nsarray

I have a NSArray of 'generic Objects' which contain the following properties

```
-name
-id
-type (question, topic or user)
```

How can I sort this array of generic object based on the generic object's type? E.g. I want to display all generic objects of type 'topic' on the top, followed by 'users' than 'questions'

Comment: This has been answered several times: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors), for example.

Comment: This question might have your answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, I want specifically to push all objects with type = topic to the top so I can't really use ascending or descending sort in this case I guess. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to define a custom sorting function, then pass it to an NSArray method that allows custom sorting. For example, using [`sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCHBAHB), you might write (assuming your types are NSString instances):

```
NSInteger customSort(id obj1, id obj2, void *context) {
    NSString * type1 = [obj1 type];
    NSString * type2 = [obj2 type];

    NSArray * order = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"topic", @"users", @"questions", nil];

    if([type1 isEqualToString:type2]) {
        return NSOrderedSame; // same type
    } else if([order indexOfObject:type1] < [order indexOfObject:type2]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending; // the first type is preferred
    } else {
        return NSOrderedAscending; // the second type is preferred
    }   
}   

// later...

NSArray * sortedArray = [myGenericArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:customSort
                                                         context:NULL];
```

If your types aren't NSStrings, then just adapt the function as needed - you could replace the strings in the `order` array with your actual objects, or (if your types are part of an enumeration) do direct comparison and eliminate the `order` array entirely.

Comment: You can also use NSArray's `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method, which takes a block as its argument. That avoids needing to write a custom function, because you can put the same comparison code inside the block.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen: good point, thanks! There's actually a whole slew (well, five) similar comparison functions on NSArray - I picked this one pretty arbitrarily. Zhen: use whichever you're most comfortable with.