# NSMutableArray(of dictionaries) Shuffling Array based on another array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

there have already been lots of questions asked for Sorting of an NSMutableArray still am unable to find the exact solution for my problem.Kindly follow up:

I have an **arrMasterArray** which is something like this:

```
    //This is an array of dictionaries with each element having dictionary at its index and key-value for the same.
    <__NSArrayM 0x8bbaca0>(
    {
        "Brand_Description" = Accolate;
        "Medication_DateStart" = "5/5/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    },{
        "Brand_Description" =Trisenox;
        "Medication_DateStart" = "5/5/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    }, {
        "Brand_Description" = Ultiva;
        "Medication_DateStart" = "5/5/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    } ,{
        "Brand_Description" = Accretropin;
        "Medication_DateStart" = "5/5/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    }
```

I apply sorting on **arrMasterArray** which returns me an sorted array but with only elements of that particular keyPath:

```
NSArray *arrNameCompare= [[arrMasterArray valueForKeyPath:@"Brand_Description"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

which outputs something like this:

> ```
> <__NSArrayI 0x10e0efb0>(
> Accolate,
> Accretropin,
> Trisenox,
> Ultiva
> )
> ```

Now i want **arrMasterArray** to get sorted according to `**arrNameCompare**`.

I searched a lot but no luck. Thanks for your patience and sorry for my english.
Thanks Again.

Comment: what hv u wrote in `compare` selector method? Its code is imp coz it actually performs the sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the NSMutableArray method, sortUsingDescriptors:. This method sorts your (mutable) array "in place" rather than creating a new array like sortedArrayUsingSelector:.  So, if I understand what you're trying to do, then these lines will sort arrMasterArray according to the values of Brand_Description:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Brand_Description" ascending:YES];
 [arrMasterArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
```

Answer (score 2):

i thnk you may read this thread. it will help you

[How to sort NSMutableArray using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors)

also for more thisone

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: The links were useful. Thanks for them :)