# Objective C - Sort Numbers From An Array While Maintaining Old Indexes

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsnumber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort NSMutableArray using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors)

I'm confused how I would go about sorting this.  I don't entirely understand NSDictionary objects but I did some searching and a lot of people recommended using them to maintain original indexs of array elements before sorting.  If there is a better way to do it, please let me know, but for right now I am adding NSDicitonary objects (with a NSNumber value + NSNumber key) to an NSMutableArray.  I then want to sort the array based on the NSNumber values.  This is how I have it set up right now:

```
NSMutableArray *sortindx = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapactiy: M] autorelease];

for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    //Each element is  a single number value with a key of its original array index
    NSDictionary *anElement=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: numbers[i]] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    [sortindx addObject: anElement];
}
```

How would I sort "sortindx" based on the values of the dictionaries without altering their keys?

My ultimate goal is something like this:

```
{100, 0}, {20, 1}, {50, 2} //before sort
{20, 1}, {50, 2},  {100,0} //after sort
```

Comment: Use sort descriptors.
This is thoroughly described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors Best, Flo

Comment: That was perfect for what I needed.  Thank you!