# Sort an NSMutableArray / Dictionary with several objects

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am having a problem that I think I am overcomplicating.

I need to make either an NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary. I am going to be adding at least two objects like below:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[results addObject: [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myValue01], @"valueLabel01", nil]];
```

This gives me the array I need but after all the objects are added I need to be able to sort the array by the first column (the integers - myValues). I know how to sort when there is a key, but I am not sure how to add a key or if there is another way to sort the array.

I may be adding more objects to the array later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick reference to another great answer for this question:

[How to sort NSMutableArray using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors)

NSSortDescriptors can be your best friend in these situations :)

Comment: No way!! I was searching for hours for this answer! Apparently I have to wait to mark as correct though. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have done here is create a list with two elements: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myValue01] and @"valueLabel01". It seems to me that you wanted to keep records, each with a number and a string? You should first make a class that will contain the number and the string, and then think about sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the sortedArrayUsingComparator: method work for you? Something like:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArray {
    return [results sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        NSNumber *number1 = [obj1 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSNumber *number2 = [obj2 objectAtIndex:0];
        return [number1 compare:number2]; }];
    }
```