# Using NSSortDescriptors, returning array is null

Tags: iphone, sorting, nssortdescriptor

with the help of StefanB's answer in [How to sort NSMutableArray using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors) I got pretty much understood and so implemented NSSortDescriptors in my project, I have Facebook Places name, description, id, long and lat coming from Facebook Graph. Then calculated the distance using my location and long-lat from Facebook Places. And saved all this in array(placesDataArray) of dictionary.

Now the problem is when trying to sort this array (placesDataArray), the return array (sortedArray) is null?

```
 NSLog(@"PLACES DATA ARRAY ===== > %@", placesDataArray);

    NSSortDescriptor * distanceDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:DISTANCE
                                                                         ascending:YES];

    id obj;
    NSEnumerator * enumerator = [placesDataArray objectEnumerator];
    while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject]));

    NSArray * descriptors =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:distanceDescriptor, nil];
    NSArray * sortedArray =
    [placesDataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    NSLog(@"\nSorted =========================>");

    enumerator = [sortedArray objectEnumerator];
    while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject]));
    NSLog(@"SORTED ARRAY ===========> \n%@", obj);
```

And my Result is:

```
> 2013-01-10 18:50:40.439 Chat.Points[12091:c07] PLACES DATA ARRAY ===== > (
        {
        category = Hotel;
        distance = "0.109";
        name = "New York Marriott Marquis";
        placeImageString = 20372413613;
    },
        {
        category = Hotel;
        distance = "0.019";
        name = "DoubleTree Suites by Hilton New York City - Times Square";
        placeImageString = 85286252698;
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
        {
        category = "Local business";
        distance = "0.229";
        name = "Le Pain Quotidien";
        placeImageString = 153110388035573;
    },
        {
        category = "Local business";
        distance = "0.074";
        name = NYSC;
        placeImageString = 144712562228653;
    },
        {
        category = "Local business";
        distance = "0.193";
        name = "The W Hotel";
        placeImageString = 113613138695956;
    },
        {
        category = "Local business";
        distance = "0.015";
        name = "Palace Theatre - Pricilla Queen Of The Desert!";
        placeImageString = 130723233698153;
    },
        {


         category = Hotel;
            distance = "0.033";
            name = "Renaissance New York Times Square Hotel";
            placeImageString = 111789988858447;
        } ) 
2013-01-10 18:50:40.500 Chat.Points[12091:c07]  Sorted =========================> 
2013-01-10 18:50:44.993 Chat.Points[12091:c07] SORTED ARRAY ===========>  
(null)
```

Please refer to the question in the link I have provided above.
The effort is very much appreciated.

Comment: what is `DISTANCE` here?

Comment: Thanks Midhun MP, 'DISTANCE' is key which is saving value of 'distance' objects, as you can see in my code for e.g.- **distance = "0.229"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort the array correctly, but you print the wrong object in the final output:

```
NSLog(@"SORTED ARRAY ===========> \n%@", obj);
```

should be

```
NSLog(@"SORTED ARRAY ===========> \n%@", sortedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin R, that was a great help, and I was a doughnut when printed the 'obj' instead of 'sortedArray'...
It's working fine! Have accepted the answer, unfortunately cannot up-vote coz of low rep, but will do it once I achieve....

Comment: @Samapple007: It there any reason that you have "unaccepted" the answer? Is there any problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

Printed the 'sortedArray' instead of 'obj'

Wrong -->

```
NSLog(@"SORTED ARRAY ===========> \n%@", obj);
```

Correct -->

```
NSLog(@"SORTED ARRAY ===========> \n%@", sortedArray);
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r