# Accessing descriptors in array of arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, descriptor

I have a mutable array containing some arrays for use in a table view controller. The arrays contain a title and some other information. I want the arrays in the master array to be sorted alphabetically in terms of the title they contain. I have assigned the titles with keys:

```
NSString *title = @"objectTitle";
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_storedTitle.text, title, nil];
NSArray *newArray = @[@"Login", dict, _storedUsername.text, _storedPassword.text];
```

I store the newArray in my masterArray and try to sort the array thus:

```
    //sort array alphabetically
    NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"objectTitle" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[titleDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [_masterArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    _masterArray = sortedArray.copy;
```

This is not working, as i have not specified the index where the titleDescriptor is stored. How do I do this?

When accessing the title at a given index (index) in the master array is done as follows:

```
     NSLog(@"%@", [[[_masterArray objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"objectTitle"]);
```

Comment: I have modified your code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code like this:-

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortedDescriptor =
        [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
         initWithKey:@"objecttitle"
         ascending:YES
                selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

NSArray * descriptors =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortedDescriptor, nil];
  NSArray * sortedArray =
 [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

NSlog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Comment: I have updated the code. It does not seem to make any difference. Crashes at         NSArray * sortedArray = [_masterArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

Comment: It means your data is not proper. Please follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors

Comment: True, I had to setup the array differently. Thank you for posting the link!